# Objective-C Sudzc WSDL Generator Alternative

Tags: objective-c, soap, wsdl, sudzc

Sudzc ([www.sudcz.com](http://www.sudzc.com)) appears that it is no longer a project that is being contributed to!

After a year of no commits and some serious bugs especially with returning list of objects this helpful tool appears to be fading into the black holes of the internet.

I was wondering if anyone knew of an alternative tool that works the same way as this?

Or are soap requests no longer a preferred method of data transfer?  Is json a better approach using rest clients?

Bonus question: Is there a way to make sudzc handle a returned list of objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some alternatives are:

- [Easy WSDL](http://easywsdl.com/)
- [Wsdl2Code](http://www.wsdl2code.com/)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18376105/883413) mentions another alternative, [wsdl2objc](https://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/).

Answer (score 0):

Within the generated SoapRequest.m file there you can find the implementation of

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection
```

Look for

```
if([deserializeTo respondsToSelector: @selector(initWithNode:)])
{
    element = [element childAtIndex:0];
    output = [deserializeTo initWithNode: element];
}
```

and remove the line with "element = [...]". If you do so keep in mind that you could have to do fixes in other parts of your generated .m files because of this change. This depends heavily on your WebService layout. Hope this helps.