# generate SOAP classes for iPhone from WSDL

Tags: iphone, ios, wsdl

in my application I need to communicate with server and I have an WSDL file, how can I generate SOAP classes for iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

I have personally used SUDZC in the past for generating SOAP services from a WSDL.

It does support both ARC and non-ARC projects but it generates some very abstract code.

Have a look at [the website](http://sudzc.com) and try it out for yourself.

If you find any other alternatives, let me know.

Internally, we write most of our request/response handlers using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) nowadays.

Comment: What do you mean by free service? Somewhere to host your web service? If that is the case, sorry. I'm not familiar with anything related to .NET.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open source SOAP bindings generator called [`wsdl2objc`](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/). Though the generated code is awful and the project seems outdated, it still works good.